# adding two lines of text to a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am looking to add two lines to a csv file using R that I have created in a loop. I begin with a number of files, named file1.csv, file2.csv, etc, each of which contain two columns of coordinates. I then use these as index matrices to create new csv files that have a '2' listed in the entry in the index file, and a '0' otherwise. I add headers to the file, so that the resulting file looks like:

```
"","1","2","3","4","5"
"1",0,0,0,0,0
"2",0,0,0,0,2
```

which is exactly what I need (my code is below). However, I need to also add two rows to the beginning of the csv file that read "min 1" and "max 3", respectively, that come before the headers, so that it would look like:

```
"min 1",,,,
"max 3",,,,
"","1","2","3","4","5"
"1",0,0,0,0,0
"2",0,0,0,0,2
```

I've tried adding rows to the M matrix, rbinding, ,merging two csvs, reading the csv file back in and trying to add the rows then, and I'm not getting anything that works. Advice is much appreciated (as well as improving my existing code which I am sure is quite inelegant).

Thank you

```
 csvdat <- list.files(pattern='file.*.csv')
 for (i in seq_along(csvdat)){
data <- read.csv(csvdat[i])
data[,2] -> x
data[,3] -> y
index=cbind(x,y)   
a <- length(x)+1    
matrix(nrow=a,ncol=a) -> M
M[] <- 0
M[index] <- 2
Cn <- c(1:a)
colnames(M) <- Cn
file <- as.character(paste("matrix", i, ".csv", sep=""))
write.csv(M, file,col.names=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you work on one case independent of the loop first? Adding the loop around later is trivial, and including it here is just an unnecessary complication. Also, why do you want to do this, have you constructed some elaborate system and now digging yourself in deeper?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of "what is the problem you are trying to solve?"   If you explain what you're doing with the output file, and why it's constrained to be in such an odd configuration, someone can probably explain a much better way to achieve your final desired result -- not just produce this particular csv file.

That said, in general you can use `write` or `write.csv` to send your "min 1,min 3" string to a file, followed by `write.csv(data,{other arguments},append=TRUE)` to place your matrix of data below the string(s).

Comment: Agree completely - whatever the task is, this doesn't sound like the optimal way of solving it...

Comment: I am using the file as input for the program Circuitscape, which requires the file in the format I describe. This file is being read in as way to calculate resistance distances only on those pairs noted with a value between min and max in my matrix file, rather than on all possible pairs (which would be the default). The output which which I begin (two columns) is the output from another program. If anyone is familiar with Circuitscape or has a better way of solving the problem, please do let me know!